# ffmpeg - define exact time distance for images

Tags: video, ffmpeg, images

I have a movie that is 3 minutes long and 29 image/sec. I want to split it into images by 1/second.

I use this command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i FILE0014.MOV -r 2 -f image2 -vcodec mjpeg -qscale 2 "%%05d.jpg"
```

but that generates more than 300 images!

The logfile shows:

> frame=    3 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=13
>   frame=    4 fps=3.9 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:01.50 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=33
>   frame=    5 fps=3.2 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:02.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=51
>   frame=    7 fps=3.4 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=67
>   frame=    8 fps=3.1 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:03.50 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=84
>   frame=    9 fps=2.9 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=102
>   frame=   10 fps=2.8 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:04.50 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=120
>   frame=   12 fps=2.9 q=0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:05.50 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=137

the time is not exact 1 second.

Could someone help me to make a correct command?

Answer (score 1):

try:

`ffmpeg -i file0014.mov -vf fps=1 -q:v 2 %03d.jpg`

Breaking this down:

`-vf fps=1` will select a frame at even 1 second intervals

`-q:v 2` (shorthand for your `qscale`) is a quality scale for jpeg images.  1 is highest quality, 31 is lowest.